Why does capturing the output of a Python subprocess fail when the subprocess generates UTF-8 output?
I'm trying to redirect the output of a subprocess to a temporary file for later reprocessing.
When the subprocess generates 7-bit output (e.g. for en-US), the redirection works and the temporary file has valid content.
When the subprocess generates full UTF-8 output (e.g., for zh-CN), the redirection fails, and the temporary file is empty.
When I run the command via the shell, the redirection works, and the output file has the desired output (whether the output is UTF-8 or not).
I've tried a bunch of slightly different variations, e.g.:
subprocess.run(args, check=True, stdout=tempfile, text=True, encoding="utf-8")

or
    target = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True)
    if target.returncode == 0:
        tempfile.write(target.stdout.decode("utf-8"))

and so forth, and they all work great, so long as the subprocess outputs 7-bit chars. Any UTF-8 output appears to be discarded.

Can you provide a command sample that outputs a text the problem can be reproduced with? Also how did you create tempfile? [SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve)).

I'm unable to reproduce this. Both methods work just fine with UTF-8 output.

Turns out the code paths weren't quite the same for the UTF-8 and non-UTF-8 files, resulting in the different behavior.
The actual problem was that the incoming work file needed to be closed beforehand.
